# Manipulate Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects that appears as follows:

```
var dataArray = [{ "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 53 },
                 { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 69 },
                 { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 52 },
                 {"moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },
                 { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },
                 { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 }]
```

What I would like to do is to put in a new array the value of the element **moment** and the average of **val** for that moment. eg:

```
result =[{moment: "18 January 2019", "val": 58},
{moment: "21 January 2019", "val": 52}].
```

For now I managed to put a single occurence of each date in the new array **result** but I am having hard time to put the average since I don't know how to make the difference between values for a date from values for another date. Any help would be appreciated.

Peace

Comment: break down the problem. #1 how to get the avg? Variable avg is gotten by `for data in dataArray` divided by `dataArray.length`. #2 do your other iteration(s)

Comment: What have attempted? Better you post that in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Here first we aggregate the values by moment and also count no. of similar moments. and than map through it and find the average using the aggregated value and count.

```js
var dataArray = [{ "moment": "18 January 2019","val": 53 },{ "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 69 },{ "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 52 },{"moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },                { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },                { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 }]
                 
let output = dataArray.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  if( op[cur.moment] ){
    op[cur.moment].val += cur.val;
    op[cur.moment].count++;
  } else {
    op[cur.moment] = cur
    op[cur.moment].count = 1;
  }
  return op;
},{})

let final = Object.values(output).map(e => {
   return {
    moment: e.moment,
    val: e.val/e.count
   } 
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalCount = 0;
var divBy = 0;
var momentToCheck = "21 January 2019"
for(int i= 0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
    if (dataArray[i].moment === momentToCheck) {
        totalCount+= dataArray[i].val;
        divBy++;
    }
}
var newAvg = totalCount/divBy;
dataArray.push({moment:momentToCheck, val:newAvg});
```

Comment: I think he wants averaged values for each date.

Comment: How about "18 January 2019" and other dates that may come later?

Comment: @PrashantZombade make a function that takes a moment as an argument, call that function in a loop.

Comment: That will make unnecessary call to the functions to and fro. It might be good idea in this case to process the input in one go.

Comment: @PrashantZombade as other posters have suggested, use `reduce()`

Comment: @Our_Benefactors thank you so much for the efforts and the discernment

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to first perform a grouping, and then to perform the average of each group. For example:

```js
const dataArray = [{ "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 53 },
                   { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 69 },
                   { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 52 },
                   { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },
                   { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },
                   { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 }]
                   
const groups = dataArray.reduce((r, { moment, val }) => {
  (r[moment] = r[moment] || []).push(val)  
  return r
}, {})

const avg = arr => arr.reduce((r, x) => r + x, 0) / arr.length

const result = Object.entries(groups).map(([moment, arr]) => ({
  moment,
  avg: avg(arr)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected result in the following way using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var dataArray = [{
        "moment": "18 January 2019",
        "val": 53
    },
    {
        "moment": "18 January 2019",
        "val": 69
    },
    {
        "moment": "18 January 2019",
        "val": 52
    },
    {
        "moment": "21 January 2019",
        "val": 52
    },
    {
        "moment": "21 January 2019",
        "val": 52
    },
    {
        "moment": "21 January 2019",
        "val": 52
    }
];

const result = dataArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
    if (!accumulator[currentValue.moment]) {
        accumulator[currentValue.moment] = array
            .filter(arr => arr.moment === currentValue.moment)
            .reduce((acc, val, idx, coll) => {
                acc += val.val;

                if (idx === coll.length - 1) {
                    return acc/coll.length;
                } else {
                    return acc;
                }
        }, 0);
    }

    return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(result); // [ '18 January 2019': 58, '21 January 2019': 52 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array reduce and inside the call back check if the arument array have moment with same value

```js
var dataArray = [{
    "moment": "18 January 2019",
    "val": 53
  },
  {
    "moment": "18 January 2019",
    "val": 69
  },
  {
    "moment": "18 January 2019",
    "val": 52
  },
  {
    "moment": "21 January 2019",
    "val": 52
  },
  {
    "moment": "21 January 2019",
    "val": 52
  },
  {
    "moment": "21 January 2019",
    "val": 52
  }
]

let avgVal = dataArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIfHasDate = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.moment === curr.moment

  });

  if (findIfHasDate === -1) {
    acc.push({
      moment: curr.moment,
      totalVal: curr.val,
      totalcount: 1

    })
  } else {
    acc[findIfHasDate].totalVal = (acc[findIfHasDate].totalVal + curr.val);
    acc[findIfHasDate].totalcount += 1;
  }

  return acc;
}, []).map((item) => {
  return {
    moment: item.moment,
    avg: (item.totalVal) / item.totalcount
  }
})

console.log(avgVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sumRow = (sum, count) => ({ sum, count })

const summarize = data => data.reduce((a, c) => (prev => (
  { ...a, [c.moment]: sumRow(prev.sum + c.val, prev.count + 1) }
))(a[c.moment] || sumRow(0, 0)), {})

const average = summary => Object.keys(summary).map(
  k => ({ moment: k, val: (summary[k].sum / summary[k].count) })
)
 
console.log(average(summarize([
  { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 53 },
  { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 69 },
  { "moment": "18 January 2019", "val": 52 },
  { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },
  { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 },
  { "moment": "21 January 2019", "val": 52 }
])))
```